# Store fetched data to avoid fetching it with each reload of the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that is supposed to be used in different views. This component is Select element with pretty long list of options, and I load this list from db via ajax call.
For all views used the same Select with the same list of options.
My problem is that I don't understand how to coerce this Select to load this list only once, and reuse it for other renderings.
It looks somewhat like this now (simplistically, obviously):

```
var SelectField = React.createClass({
        loadListFromServer: function () {...}
        getInitialState()
        {
            return {
                options: [],
            };
        },

        componentDidMount() {
            this.setState({
                options: this.loadListFromServer()
            });
        },

        render: function () {
          return (
          <div>
             <Select options={this.state.options} />
          </div>
            );
        }
    })
    ;

var Index = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
                    <SelectField />
        );
    }
});

var Content = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
                    <SelectField />
        );
    }
});

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
            <Route path="/" component={Index}/>
            <Route path="path" component={Content}/>
        </Router>,
        document.getElementById("container")
    )
```

What I tried to do: make both `options` and `loadListFromServer()` global and call the `loadListFromServer()` from `window.init`. Then `Index` renders with empty `options` as it is being filled when everything is already mounted. 
So what is general approach to achieve it? Thanks, and I am sorry if my question is stupid - I've just started this topic.

Comment: why can't you do the react stuff from an ajax callback when you have the data in-scope?

Comment: You mean something like that?  `window.onload = init;
function init() {
    loadListFromServer(),

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
            <Route path="/" component={Index}>

            </Route>
            <Route path="path2"component={Content}/>
        </Router>,
        document.getElementById("container")
    )
};
` I didn't think about that, I am afraid it could breed some strange bugs, no?

Comment: Also, it still doesn't work, `Index` renders before fetching is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you only want to load the `<Select>` component once, I assume you mean you only want to load its **data** once.

You might try a **flux** architecture that separates components from actions.

The root of the problem in your example seems to be the tight coupling between the `<Select>` component and the state that it presents (the list of options). Every time the component is used, it must create its state or reuse the state from a different instance of `<Select>`. But in the latter case we would need somewhere to store the state between different instances of the component.

Have you looked into [redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux)? It decouples the state from components.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I think that's what I am looking for, will try.